# Order of printf?

Tags: bash, printf

I'm wondering why the following prints the first command last?

```
file=$(printf .tar.gz & printf test)
echo $file
```

It outputs `test.tar.gz` but I'd expect `.tar.gztest`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of [asynchronous commands](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03_02) is not guaranteed and shall depend on the shell and operating system scheduler.

A simple test (run with `zsh` on Mac OSX El Capital):

```
for shell in bash ksh zsh mksh yash dash; do
  printf '[%s]\n' "$shell"
  "$shell" -c 'file=$(printf .tar.gz & printf test); echo "$file"'
done
[bash]
test.tar.gz
[ksh]
test.tar.gz
[zsh]
.tar.gztest
[mksh]
.tar.gztest
[yash]
test.tar.gz
[dash]
test.tar.gz
```

On my Ubuntu 14.04 VM, all of those shells produce `test.tar.gz`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `&` sends the first command to background, and after finishing `printf test` the background command from the subshell shows the info before the subshell exits. producing a `test.tar.gz`

in debug mode you can see the order of the commands as

```
++ printf test
++ printf .tar.gz
+ file=test.tar.gz
+ echo test.tar.gz
```

Hope is a bit clearer now,

Comment: No, the order isn't guaranteed